# Space efficient data structure for subsets of [1:n]

Tags: data-structures, sets, space-analysis

Let $S= \{1,2,3...,n\}$ be a set and I want to store a subset of $A \subseteq S$. Is there exists any data structure such that insert$(x)$, delete ($x$) can be done in amortised $O(1)$ time and search($x$) can be done in $O(1)$ time, where $x\in A$. Space used by data structure should be $O(n \log^{*}n)$ or $O(n)$ bits. Model of computation is RAM.

Answer (score 2):

[Bit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) fulfill all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Bit vectors, as mentioned by Raphael, fulfill all the requirements and it is a very simple and fast option.
But there is an alternative called Minimal Perfect Hashing, which could be represented succinctly requiring few bits in practice.

A bit vector $B$ can also be compressed in order to achieve $$O(nH_0(B)) \text{ 
bits}$$ of space. Depending on the distribution of 0's and 1's, this could be $o(n)$ bits.